# Click event handler fires on ready but not on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a button that is added by jquery/ajax and I want to get it's value(number) from it when clicked. The problem is that it never fires. If I have on click even in the .ready it fires on load if outside it does nothing happens at all.

```
$('.page').on("click", function(event){
    alert("clicked");
}

<button class="page">1</button>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try instead:

```
$('body').on("click", ".page", function(event){
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Since your element is added dynamically, you need to bind the click event based on an element that exists when the page loads. Ideally you want an element that's closer in the DOM than the body, but worst case you can use that.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: Doh! I actually thought of that at one point but I guess it was late so I forgot to try it :) Thanks for almost instant answer!

Comment: I bind my ajax call on click event... but it still loaded on document ready? any thought as of why?

Comment: @wlin - Impossible to tell from your comment. Create a question and be sure to post your code.